# Runtime 91 & 1004 error in vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the defect and status from reporting tool.

First thing I am getting:

> Runtime error : 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Then if I debug it, I am getting the following error:

> Runtime error 1004: application defined or object defined error

on code below:

`Sheet2.Rows(i, 1).Value = DefectNo`

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Defects_Click()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "Reporting tool URL"
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document
    Dim status As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim DefectNo As Variant
    For i = 1 To 100
        DefectNo = doc.getElementsByClassName("cn_formattedid0")(i).innerText
        status = doc.getElementsByClassName("cn_state0")(i).innerText
        Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Rows(i, 1).Value = DefectNo
        Sheet2.Rows(i, 2).Value = status
    Next i
    IE.Quit
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheet2.Rows(i, 2).Value   ====> not Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value

Comment: Your problem looks like youre trying to apply a value to the entire row. You might want to assign a value to a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this,

```
Sheet2.Rows(i, 1).Value = DefectNo
Sheet2.Rows(i, 2).Value = status
```

to this,

```
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = DefectNo
Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value = status
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Runtime error 1004: application defined or object defined error resolved.  But am getting Runtime error : 91 object variable or with block variable not set error. This is not resolved. :(